# Do I need to use filebeat with logstash when dealing with local logs?

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I'm trying to understand use-cases when I should use filebeat with logstash. For instance, if logstash can read input local log files, do I need to use filebeat for that or only use logstash? My understanding that filebeat is useful when reading remote log files and send them to logstash server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have one machine for your application and are running logstash on it as well, you would not need filebeat.  When you scale up to multiple app servers, then add it in.